# Nested Term ElasticSearch 7 problem / Elastica Don't work - BEGINNER

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elastica

I'm trying to get exact search with slug in nested element in ElasticSearch but it seems like that it doesn't work.

So when i'm trying a simple nested **match** with **"my-slug"** i get result with **"my"** and **"slug"**, Normal...

```
GET my-index/_search
  
  {
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "productTranslation",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "productTranslation.slug": "my-slug"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

**But i have no result when i'm trying with term or filter search.**

```
GET my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "productTranslation",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "productTranslation.slug": "my-slug"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Any idea where the error lies??**

Thank's for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Term query doesn't perform any analysis on the term. So, in [term query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html) you need to have an exact match.**

If you have not explicitly defined any mapping then you need to add `.keyword` to the `productTranslation.slug` field. This uses the keyword analyzer instead of the standard analyzer (notice the ".keyword" after `productTranslation.slug` field).

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "productTranslation",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "filter": [
            {
              "term": {
                "productTranslation.slug.keyword": "my-slug"  // note this
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

OR you can change the data type of the `productTranslation.slug` field to keyword type

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "productTranslation": {
        "properties": {
          "slug": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @Titeufggg please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Thank you for your help.

I Added   **"type": "keyword"** to mapping and it works !